# How to handle private repositories without storing keys on server with ansible

Tags: git, ansible

My problem is that I don't want to store GitHub keys on the server, because I'm not the only user with root privileges.

The only way I can pull code from GitHub should be by ansible-playbook.

I have a simple Django app which I want to deploy only from my private computer.

I tried to user agent forwarding but it is much slower than without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use access tokens.
All the information can be found here:

https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line

Comment: Wow, that's actually what I need, thank you very much!
But I'm wondering if it's a good practise or is there better way to do this.

Comment: It's the recommended way, This is what it made for.